# Why does runghc fail when using -XSafe?

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to run some Safe Haskell code with `runghc`, but it doesn't seem to work for me.

```
bgeron@tinker:/tmp/wtf$ ls
Strange.hs
bgeron@tinker:/tmp/wtf$ cat Strange.hs 
module Strange where

main :: IO ()
main = do
    return ()
bgeron@tinker:/tmp/wtf$ runghc -XSafe Strange

Strange:1:1: Not in scope: `System.Environment.withArgs'
bgeron@tinker:/tmp/wtf$ runghc --version
runghc 7.6.3
```

I thought this would be a valid use of `runghc`; the error is most confusing. Is this a bug?

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04, 64-bit.

Comment: not confusing. add `import System.Environment`.

Comment: The orig program works for me on ghc 7.4.1 under Ubuntu 12.04, but fails under ghc 7.8.3 in HaskellPlatform 14.2.0.0 under Win7. Adding the import is unneccesary because the code doesn't call `getArgs` nor any function in `System.Environment` and furthermore, doesn't fix the problem (for me, on HaskellPlatform 14.2.0.0 on Win7).

Comment: ok now I see that it's strange. I cannot reproduce your bug with ghc-7.8.3 on fedora. Can you show the output of `runghc -v Strange.hs`?

Comment: Thanks @ja! It seems to be a bug. I'll report it soon.

Comment: @d8d0d65b3f7cf42: See https://gist.github.com/bgeron/a3c3cb0866d28e6f3039 .

Comment: @d8d0d65b3f7cf42 : For `runghc -v -XSafe Strange.hs` (which triggers the bug), see https://gist.github.com/bgeron/a165c2d973a9578a1c14.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The observed behaviour can be explained by the following.

The implementation of `runghc` is here: 
https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/browser/ghc/utils/runghc/runghc.hs

It will make the following call to `ghc`, which also shows the strange behaviour:

```
ghc -XSafe -e ':main' Strange.hs
```

The implementation of ghc in evalatue-expression mode will add the offending import:
https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/browser/ghc/ghc/InteractiveUI.hs#L1154

I am not sure whether it's a bug. I agree it's confusing.

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned in the comment, just add `import System.Environment`